# Unable to remove an object from an IList<T> using delegate <Action> method| C# Console Application

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, action

Here is my list:
 `public  IList<Food> Foods { get; } = new List<Food>();`

The generic method which recives IList and an Action as it's argument:

```
public void Process<T>(IList<T> items, Action<IList<T>> disposal)
{
     disposal(items);
}
```

The way I did inside Main method:

```
using Generics03.Models;
using Generics03.Systems;

Multislut ms=new Multislut(){};
ms.Foods.Add(new Food());
ms.Foods.Add(new Food());
ms.Foods.Add(new Food());

ms.Process<Food>(ms.Foods,(f)=>{
    f[0].Name="Pizza";
    f[0].Region="Italy";
    
    //when adding the following method, the project doesn't run!
    f.GrowKale();

    //Composter.cs where the Growkale method is defined in
public static class Composter
{
     public static void GrowKale(this IList<Food> foods)
     {
           foreach (var item in foods)
           {
                foods.Remove(item);
           }           
      }    
}
```

All I need to do is to remove `ms.Foods` objects that I've added in `Program.cs/Main()`, I'm able to assign value to their properties but not able to remove or even add object to the `ms.Foods` list, getting the following exception message:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: If you need to remove everything, why not use foods.Clear()?

Comment: Within the `foreach` you can't call `.Remove()` on the same list. If you like to remove all elements call `.Clear()`. If you need to remove a part, materialize the list of affected items into its own list before calling remove on original list. Easiest example would be `foreach (var item in foods.ToList())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a copy of the `List` before you try remove items,

You can't remove items from the `List` you are Enumerating without throwing the exception you are seeing, This is to stop you from creating situations where you end up with new and old values and forces you to start again.

The easiest way to do this is with `.ToList()`

```
       foreach (var item in foods.ToList())
       {
            foods.Remove(item);
       }
```

to make it easier to read/understand you could also do this

```
       var theComposter = foods.ToList();
       foreach (var food in theComposter)
       {
            foods.Remove(food);
       }
```

You should also consider using a `lock` whenever you try to get/set the `foods` so you don't see this error again if you use multiple threads.